# How to install Python Pandas?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pandas, package

I have a huge problem with Python packages. I'm completely newbie when it comes to Python and I'm having trouble for a long time. Anyway, I succeed in installing NumPy package and after that I can't install anything by simply using `python setup.py install` in the terminal.

I'd like to install pandas package, but I'm getting the same error every time:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-539.pth'.
```

I went one step backward and tried to install "pip" and/or "setuptools", but I'm getting the same error `[Errno 13]` every time.

Is there a way to "easily" or even "understandably" install Python packages.

Comment: I try not to mess too much with the system python installation, and personally I prefer using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) for setting up my python development area where I can manage separate python environments.

Answer (score 5):

Permission denied error stems from not having write access when installing a package. On unix like systems the command is "sudo".

So, whatever package manager you use to download pandas, whichever package, start the command with "sudo" to ensure that you grant yourself write access for a download.

Example: (This is for a Linux box)

```
sudo apt-get install pip
```

And then with pip (the python package manager)

```
pip install <package-name>
```

With a Mac, you would either have to use homebrew or macports as your package manager.

Install homebrew like this:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then use brew to install pip

```
brew install pip
```

And just as before pip to install python packages

```
pip install <package-name>
```

Comment: Depending on what version of OS X she or he is running, `brew install python` may be advisable instead of just installing `pip`, in the interest of having the latest Python release; older versions of OS X included 2.5 or 2.6.

Comment: @jgysland Yes! I forgot the most important part. Actually having python installed to the local system. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is not the answer to your question, but Anaconda works flawless for Linux. But I guess it is the same for Apple: http://continuum.io/downloads#py34

Comment: The challenge in managing python packages is exactly the reason ananconda was created.  fully loaded python + 100 packages for scientific and data applications installer.

Answer (score 1):

While installing `pandas`, I had the error of

> 'Could not install packages due to environmental errors: ...'

while uninstalling `python-dateutil 1.5` .

It was solved using this command.

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed python-dateutil pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use easy_install too:

first install easy_install tool and then use it like:

```
easy_install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help!!!

I'll suggest everyone facing the same problem to install brew and then follow the steps posted above.

If you still have problem ([Errno 13]), try with "sudo su" first, then follow the installation steps you need.

Best,
Zona

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following.
sudo easy_install pandas